# JSOUP - Extract Data of a Div Tag

Tags: html, jsoup

Hello I'm trying to extract the price. Can anyone please help me? There is no output for the price

**Html**

```
<div id="product-price-box" class="prod_pricebox price_details" property="gr:hasPriceSpecification">
    <div class="prod_pricebox_price">
        <div class="prod_pricebox_price_final">
            <span id="product_price" class="hidden">389.00</span>
            <span id="special_price_box">RM 389.00</span>
        </div>
        <div id="special_price_area" class=" prod_pricebox_price_special">
            <span id="product_special_price_label">Before</span>
            <span class="price_erase">
                <span id="product_price_prefix" class="price-prefix-detail"></span>
                <span id="price_box">RM 449.00,</span>
            </span>
        <div class="prod_saving">
            <span id="product_saving_label">You save</span>
            <span id="product_saving_percentage" class="price_highlight"> 13%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jsoup**

```
String url = "http://www.lazada.com.my/asus-zenfone-c-zc451cg-16gb-white-2801812.html";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

//Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.lazada.com.my/").followRedirects(true).get();
String title = doc.title();
System.out.println("title is: " + title);  
String price = doc.select("span[id=prod_pricebox_price]").text();
System.out.println("Price is: " + price);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String price = doc.select("[class=product-price]").text();`.
The selectors you've used belongs to some `JavaScript` that runs on the page, so `JSUOP` is not useful for it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your selection (`"span[id=prod_pricebox_price]"`), you are trying to select a span element with an id of prod_pricebox_price, which doesn't exist anywhere in this document.

You might want to try something like `"span#price_box"`, which should give you the element `<span id="price_box">RM 449.00,</span>`

Comment: still no output @gigadot

Comment: Try `span#special_price_box`

Comment: @pshemo can you please help me